# trying to Match multiple columns with Vlookup but flawed

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, evaluate

```
=+IF(VLOOKUP(F8,Issue!U:U,1,0)<>"#N/A","Done",
IF(VLOOKUP(Q8,Issue!P:P,1,0)<>"#N/A","Done",
IF(VLOOKUP(O8,Issue!R:R,1,0)<>"#N/A","Done","#N/A")))
```

Above formula has been used first branch of vlookup is wrong fine but failed to evaluate others.

Comment: I think you mistake the error text `#N/A` for being a text string. Don't you mean `=IF(not(isna(VLOOKUP(F8,Issue!U:U,1,0))),"Done",
IF(not(isna(VLOOKUP(Q8,Issue!P:P,1,0))),"Done",
IF(not(isna(VLOOKUP(O8,Issue!R:R,1,0)),"Done","#N/A")))` ?

Comment: could you please add sample data and expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you describe what you're trying to do as an output, and what your data format is?

If you're trying to match based on multiple criteria, try:
`=Index(match(1,(Range1=Value1)*(Range2=Value2)*... ,0))` entered with Ctrl+shift-enter

Comment: I need to match a value from another sheet based on 3 different lookup values in one sheet and 3 different column arrays in another sheet and its output is printed as "Done" in the first sheet.  My data contains a simple Excel table format.

Comment: I think you Westy means you need to apply the logic as suggested but turn it into your logic: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(Issue!U:U=F8)+(Issue!P:P=Q8)+(Issue!R:R=O8),0)),"Done",NA())` entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`